# I can't find process.server in nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js

the nuxt.js's docs say that we should use process.server instand of isServer. When the middleware was running,I console.log(process) but I can't find process.server.
why?

Comment: `process.server` is being replaced by its hardcoded value on build so `if (process.server)` will be replaced by `if (true)`, but if you only check `process`, than the value won't be replaced and will be undefined in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from a middleware, it should work

```
// middleware/demo.js

export default function () {
  console.log(process.server) // if true check your server log, if false check your browser log
}
```

see my example https://github.com/NicoPennec/nuxt-weather/blob/master/middleware/check-renderer.js